# App Sync pushing objects in dynamodb under "items" key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am trying to insert values in dynamodb through app sync. The create mutator would push the values with key as auto generated id and values under input.
I want them to be inserted in a flat manner.

Current:
{
id:'id1'
   input:{
      key:'val'
     }
}
what I want:
{
id:'id1'
key:'val'
}

Comment: please attach your appsync mutation code.

Comment: Specifically, the part of your schema where the `mutation` is defined,  and the request mapping template for the resolver.